# Output in SQL Table : without using JOIN

Tags: sql, join

I've got 2 tables that have to be joined together without them joining up together.

Table 1.

```
130,    'HANSEN',   'ZIP1'
130,    'HANSEN',   'ZIP2'
130,    'HANSEN',   'ZIP3'
120,    'HANSEN',   'ZIP4'
120,    'HANSEN',   'ZIP5'
```

Table 2.

```
130,    'HANSEN',   'ZIP1'
130,    'HANSEN',   'ZIP2'
130,    'HANSEN',   'ZIP3'
120,    'HANSEN',   'ZIP4'
120,    'HANSEN',   'ZIP5'
```

Wanted outcome.

```
130,    'HANSEN',   'ZIP1'
130,    'HANSEN',   'ZIP2'        
130,    'HANSEN',   'ZIP3'
120,    'HANSEN',   'ZIP4'
120,    'HANSEN',   'ZIP5'
130,    'HANSEN',   'ZIP1'
130,    'HANSEN',   'ZIP2'
130,    'HANSEN',   'ZIP3'
120,    'HANSEN',   'ZIP4'
120,    'HANSEN',   'ZIP5'
```

test script if someone is willing to help.

```
DROP TABLE TEST1;
DROP TABLE TEST2;

CREATE TABLE TEST1 ( ID  INTEGER ,key  VARCHAR(50),VALUE1 VARCHAR(50));
CREATE TABLE TEST2 ( ID  INTEGER ,key  VARCHAR(50),VALUE2 VARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO TEST1 VALUES (130,  'HANSEN',   'STREET1');
INSERT INTO TEST1 VALUES (130,  'HANSEN',   'STREET2');
INSERT INTO TEST1 VALUES (130,  'HANSEN',   'STREET3');
INSERT INTO TEST1 VALUES (120,  'HANSEN',   'STREET5');
INSERT INTO TEST1 VALUES (120,  'HANSEN',   'STREET6');

INSERT INTO TEST2 VALUES (130,  'HANSEN',   'ZIP1');
INSERT INTO TEST2 VALUES (130,  'HANSEN',   'ZIP2');
INSERT INTO TEST2 VALUES (130,  'HANSEN',   'ZIP3');
INSERT INTO TEST2 VALUES (120,  'HANSEN',   'ZIP4');
INSERT INTO TEST2 VALUES (120,  'HANSEN',   'ZIP5');
```

**Note that the actual data are not duplicates**

Comment: just use `UNION` the two queries

Comment: This question needs renaming so it doesn't use the word join!

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32bd6/1

Comment: Are you saying you just want to append one table to another? That’s what the first part looks like. But the second makes it look like you’re trying to do something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perform a union between the two tables:

```
select * from test1
union
select * from test2
```

If you want to retain duplicates in the result set use U NION ALL

**SQL Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32bd6/2

Comment: @Brein BTW do you want to keep duplicate records between the tables?

Comment: Yes some records will be duplicates in the real data and this has to stay that way.

Comment: Then use U NION ALL for some reason SO won't let me type U NION ALL hence the space, just remove that.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the UNION clause. To keep duplicates you would have to use UNION ALL. To eliminate them use UNION without ALL.

```
select id, key, value1 from test1
union all
select id, key, value2 from test2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [UNION](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) key word.

Just make sure that the values in the select clause are Identical in both queries.

```
SELECT ID , key, Value1 as Value
FROM Test1

UNION

SELECT ID ,key, Value2 as Value
FROM Test2
```

If you want to enable duplicate rows, replace the `UNION` with `UNION ALL`